# How to passing image view from fragment loaded by retrofit to childfragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, fragment, pass-data

so i have 1 main fragment and 2 childfragmnet, i want to pass the image view from main fragment to childfragment without Get Request retrofit again in that 2 childfragment how to do that??

i have already try this in my main Fargment :

```
private lateinit var imgFile: File
```

......

```
intent.putExtra("resId", imgFile)
```

and than call that in child fragment :

```
val bundle: Bundle = intent.extras
    val resId: Int = bundle.getInt("resId")
    binding.imgmainac.setImageResource(resId)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always directly accrss your parent fragment fields directly from child fragment

Try like this

```
(parentFragment as MainFragment).imgFile
```

Comment: can you please show me more code to do this sir?

Comment: this one line would be enough. No need to do more code

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing 2 things here:

- a resId is just an Int identifying an internal app resource.
- a file

A file is not a resId or an Int.

So if you already have a file, I would suggest:

- put the file URI as a String in your bundle (it can be obtained using file.toURI().toString())
- retrieve it using Uri.parse(bundle.getString(...))
- set it on the ImageView using .setImageURI(...)

Edit:

So to summarize:

On sender's end

```kotlin
    intent.putExtra("imageUri", file.toURI().toString())
```

On receiver's end

```kotlin
    val bundle = intent.extras
    val imageUri = bundle?.getString("imageUri")?.let { Uri.parse(it) }
    imageView.setImageURI(imageUri)
```